# Trigger a CSS Animation on scroll using javascript and not jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I trigger the CSS animation for the svg paths using javascript? Tried a lot of ways.
Here i have added a text which is basically a svg image. The animation works correctly and all i want is that the animation triggers only when scrolled.

```css
* {
  background-color: black;
}

.banner {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
}

#logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

#logo path:nth-child(1) {
  stroke-dasharray: 545px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 545px;
  animation: line-anim 2s ease forwards;
}

#logo path:nth-child(2) {
  stroke-dasharray: 303px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 303px;
  animation: line-anim 2s ease forwards .3s;
}

#logo path:nth-child(3) {
  stroke-dasharray: 439px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 439px;
  animation: line-anim 2s ease forwards .6s;
}

#logo path:nth-child(4) {
  stroke-dasharray: 526px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 526px;
  animation: line-anim 2s ease forwards .9s;
}

#logo path:nth-child(5) {
  stroke-dasharray: 525px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 525px;
  animation: line-anim 2s ease forwards 1.2s;
}

@keyframes line-anim {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move all animation css to a separate class except the animation-delay. Add Scroll listener and add this class to the logo.

```js
document.addEventListener('scroll', function() {

  document.querySelector('.logo').classList.add('logo-animation')

})
```

```css
.logo-animation {
  animation:line-anim 2s ease forwards 
}

#logo:path {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
```

Comment: i tried but didn't work! see the complete html and css code here. https://codepen.io/_neoflies_/pen/xxZPMZP

Comment: @neoflies I edited the codepen with the approach, now the animation is happening on scroll or mousewheel. https://codepen.io/_neoflies_/pen/xxZPMZP?editors=1010

Comment: can you share the code here? I am unable to find it!

Comment: Sorry I did n't save in the code pen, here is the correct link https://codepen.io/rohinikumar4073/pen/jOWzxJe

Comment: And in case i have some content above it? It will get completed till i reach there! Can you come up with another alternative? I'm sorry! I might be bothering you too much! But what if the para that I have added in comment really shows up in the page? Then the SVG gets completed before I even reach there!

Comment: You could use IntersectionObserver for your use cases.This helps to to know if your box reached the content. https://codepen.io/rohinikumar4073/pen/jOWzxJe